# Map(int,int) expected by post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-post

What format would I need to send my form post request to an API expecting the value to be map(int,int)? Or should I serialize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, Javascript has weak type checking.

Second, your value will either be a `String` or a `Number` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

My guess is you're sending a string (if it's in quotes).  Try using `parseInt(theValue)` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) on the values to convert them if you need integers.